# Update the value in the Date Picker when erased explicitly

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm using a form in my **Angular Project** where I have a input type of text which is acting as a datepicker in my project. Everything is working fine except this weird situation which I'm facing and trying hard to get out of it. 
So the problem is in my date picker when I select some date so it is coming fine in my console, but when I erase the date from the date picker it does not trigger this check at all `if(value == "")`, or I must say this is not updating when I erase the value. If I hit the value it is coming fine but erasing doesn't affect it which is making my work a little but tight.

My code is like this :

**1. HTML File**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Search for date">
</form>
```

**2. Typescript File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upcoming-page',
  templateUrl: './upcoming-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upcoming-page.component.css']
})
export class UpcomingPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     $("#date").datepicker({
       onSelect: this.onDateChosen.bind(this)
     })
  }
}

onDateChosen(value){
  console.log(value)

  if (value == ""){
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is :

1. Tried using **[(ngModel)]="dateValue"** to bind the data and get the result when I erase some data to be updated in the back end also. And then in the method i.e., in **onDateChosen()'s check** `if(this.dateValue == "" || this.dateValue == null)`, but it didn't work out.
2. Tried `if(!value)` but also it didn't work out.

It is actually not going in this check, when you erase the dates in the date picker yourself. And when you select the date from the date-picker, it is coming fine in the console.

Any help would be highly appreciated, since I'm trying hard to get it what I want. And if there is some doubts, do ask me, I'll provide the edits. Thanks

Comment: Why not link an event handler to it? (change)="onDateChosen($event)" then check what $event.value is?

Comment: onSelect does not get triggered on empty string therefore u will never be able to check `if(this.dateValue == "" || this.dateValue == null)` on `onDateChosen`

Comment: @rrd The change will also help you to check whether some date is chosen and changes is there or not when some other dates are chosen. Mine date picking is working fine. But when you erase the data from the input box and the result becomes empty, it is not getting updating it

Comment: @elvis_ferns I got it somehow, but could you please help me as in what should be done then?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly triggering  `onDateChosen` on empty value

In your .ts file

```
onDateChange($event){
  $event.target.value || this.onDateChosen($event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Not working what I have done is in my html file added `(change)="onDateChange($event)"` and in my .ts file this `ngAfterViewInit() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
      onDateChange($event){
        $event.target.value || this.onDateChosen($event.target.value)
      }
    })
  }`. Now the value is not getting passed at all even when I select some dates

Comment: Well ngAfterViewInit() only gets called once, not every time you change the date value. That's why you add the onDateChange() function in your class.

Comment: use the `keyup` event and not the `change` event.

`$("#date").datepicker({ onDateChange($event){ $event.target.value || this.onDateChosen($event.target.value) }` what exactly are you doing

Comment: Picking up the date from the date picker and if I erase the date by myself I need to populate all the data, not the filtered one

Comment: why are you trying to erase the data by yourself. Cant get your needcase